# How can I use Obfuscar to obfuscate Unity's Assembly-CSharp.dll?

Tags: c#, dll, unity-game-engine, obfuscation, obfuscar

I'm trying to obfuscate a unity3d dll `Assembly-CSharp.dll` with some free stuff.

I've found [Obfuscar](https://obfuscar.codeplex.com/) that seems good. Googling I've found [this from Babelfor](http://www.babelfor.net/Kb/Article/8), that seems good as starting point, but I've some issues trying to create a valid configuration xml.

How can I use Obfuscar to successfully obfuscate Unity's Assembly-CSharp.dll?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how can I configure to obtain a working dll in unity that's obfuscated :)

Comment: I don't have any experience with that particular solution, but obfuscation for Unity is a tricky beast at best, up to a point where we have deemed it a pointless endeavour.

Comment: Obfuscar has its documentation athttps://obfuscar.codeplex.com/documentation. Not very easy to get started but you might try. Another option is to use Confuser who has a wizard to guide you, https://github.com/yck1509/ConfuserEx/wiki/Basic-Usage